# Is it possible to skip a line in a data file?

Tags: c++, file-io

I have a data file that I am trying to input and the data is split into sections via a blank line. The data will be read in from a text file.

How do I make my code skip a blank line to read in the next piece of data? I am currently just in the planning stages of my application.

I'm a beginner so I'm not really sure how to go about this.

Can anyone advise a method on how to approach this?

I have just written it out and my code looks like this:

```
        string  ship2_id;
        char ship2_journey_id[20];
        float ship2_l; 
        int ship2_s;

        getline(itinerary_file, ship2_id);

        if (ship2_id = ' ')
        {
            itinerary_file.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

        }
        else
getline(itinerary_file, ship2_id);
cout << ship2_id << endl;
```

Comment: How do you think a blank line is represented in a file? Think about it. Think about it again. Again...

Comment: Show us your attempt please.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

```
stream.ignore(max_number_of_chars_to_be_skipped, '\n');
```

I usually just use `1ul<<30` or similar for the first parameter, but

- this could be a DoS vector if the input is untrusted and slow to skip those chars
- the "pedant" value would read `std::numeric_limits<std::stream_pos>::max()` or similar

Answer (score 0):

I don't what are you using to read the file, but, to search for a blank line, look for two "line breaks" together. Take in account that the "line breaker" character is different for some OS. In Windows, by default, there are two characters that are used together for a line break.